# loop through x number of datalist dropdown in php

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, variables

I have a php page which consists of 3 datalist dropdowns populated from a sqlite database file (comics.db).

I'm trying to save code by using a for loop (I need three dropdowns) but when I click 'submit query' the form action 'page.php' is not producing the three inputs selected by the user i.e. character[1], character[2] and character[3].

I've tried various combinations of this line:

`echo '<input list="characters" name="character[$x]">';`

but I keep getting a blank page.php. I assume the _POST variable is not storing the three inputs from the index.php page?

I've been stuck on this for a few days, I've tried session variables but can't find an answer that works other than repeating the block of code three times with name=character1, 2, 3 etc...
Surely there's a loop/array that works?

please help!

My index.php page:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
        $this->open('comics.db');
    }
}
for ($x = 1;$x < 4;$x++) {
    $db = new MyDB();
    $sql = <<<EOF
      select character_name from characters group by character_name order by character_name asc;
EOF;
    $ret = $db->query($sql);
    echo '<form action="page.php" method="post">';
    echo '<label for="character">Character: </label>';
    echo '<input list="characters" name="character[$x]">';
    echo '<datalist id="characters">';
    while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        unset($name);
        $name = $row['character_name'];
        echo '<option value=""></option>';
        echo '<option value="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</datalist>";
    $db->close();
}
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
echo '</form>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

My page.php:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

for($x = 1; $x < 4; $x++) {
  if(isset($_POST['character[$x]'])) {
    $character = $_POST['character[$x]'];
    echo "$character";
    }
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

page.php produces a blank page because this `if(isset($_POST['character[$x]']))` is *never true*.

Choose "Inspect Element" for one of the input elements to see that they all say:

```
<input list="characters" name="character[$x]">
```

It has taken the "$x" literally here:

```
echo '<input list="characters" name="character[$x]">';
```

That is because the [string is enclosed in single quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), the "$x" does not get expanded.

This `$_POST['character']` will be a list, with one element whose key is "$x";   "$x" is literal, no relation to the `$x` in the loop. If you want to see any results at all, change occurences of this `$_POST['character[$x]']` to this `$_POST['character']['$x']`.

That's probably not the result you are looking for. An easier solution is let the browser do it! If your input elements are built this way

```
echo '<input list="characters" name="character[]">';
```

the browser will send `$_POST['character']` array, that you can iterate in page.php. Naturally you'll have to make changes to page.php to properly iterate through `$_POST['character']` to display the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help!

I amended the line in index.php to:

```
echo '<input list="characters" name="character[]">';
```

and changed my page.php to the following:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['character']); $x++)
{
   echo $_POST['character'][$x];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This gives the desired result.
The following code snippet also gives the desired result

```
foreach ($_POST['NAME'] as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

@DinoCoderSaurus - many thanks for the informative answer and pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Apologies - made another typo.... $_POST['NAME'] should be $_POST['character'] above...